# SonarQube Analysis Hangs with Oracle

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I having SonarQube 5.1.2. Every so often analysis hangs. Below is the analysis log snippet at where it hangs.

```
[INFO] [11:41:24.995] Sensor CPD Sensor (done) | time=65ms
[INFO] [11:41:24.996] No quality gate is configured.
[INFO] [11:41:25.210] Execute decorators...
[INFO] [11:41:26.008] Store results in database
[INFO] [11:41:26.585] Analysis reports generated in 69ms, dir size=21 KB
[INFO] [11:41:26.630] Analysis reports compressed in 45ms, zip size=11 KB
```

In the log the last entry I see is following SQL,

> 2016.07.12 16:45:58 TRACE web[sql] time=0ms | sql=select ar.id    from analysis_reports ar    where ar.report_status=?    and not exists(
>   select 1    from analysis_reports ar2    where ar.project_key =
>   ar2.project_key    and ar2.report_status=?    )    order by
>   ar.created_at asc, ar.id asc

Please suggest what is causing this.

Comment: What is the state of the Oracle database (processes, locks, ...) when this happens? Consider also an upgrade to SonarQube 5.6

Comment: I could not find any locks on DB. I have this issue on our 11g as well a 12c schema hosted on separate DB severs. The subsequent runs succeeds. Also as you can see it hangs after "[INFO] [11:41:26.008] Store results in database". This seems to hang at sending reports to server. We eventually will upgrade to 5.6 or Later. However in the mean time if there are any parameter tuning that can be done?

Comment: Could you try the default database (see the SonarQube configuration file) and run some analysis? Make a backup of your SonarQube folder before changing the database.